# Print file names in a directory to a txt file by last modified date

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I got these 2 commands:

```
dir /s /b /o:gn>yourfile.txt
```

This gets all subfolders of current directory and prints them in the file

```
forfiles /P Downloads /S /D +12/04/2021
```

This gets files in the specified directory that were modified since 12th March 2021**

Is there a way to merge these 2 together? To print all the subfolders in a txt file since the last modified date? In this case 12th April 2021.

Comment: The first command line you've provided does not do what you stated. It lists all files and directories, ordered by name but listing all of the directories first. The date you've provided is not the 12th March 2021, it is 12th April 2021. Your second command line, does not get files in the specified directory either, it gets both files and directories. If you want a list of modified directories since a certain date, then use `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /D +12/04/2021 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C If @IsDir==TRUE Echo @RelPath"`, and for files only, change `TRUE` to `FALSE`.

Comment: If you want to print the output to a text file then use the same redirection suffix mechanism, as used in your first example command `> "X:\Somewhere\OutputResults.txt"`, _and probably, not in the same tree your command is recursing_.

Comment: Yes, there is (almost certainly at least) a way: take a look at the [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)…

Answer (score 0):

The "manfile" of `forfiles` (`forfiles /?`) mentions the `-S` switch for using subdirectories:

```
    /S                  Instructs forfiles to recurse into
                        subdirectories. Like "DIR /S".
```

So, instead of `forfiles /P`, you use `forfiles /S /P`. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: The 2 commands as they are, are good, I just want to find a way to merge those 2 commands together into 1 if possible. I want to print into a txt file since a last modified date.

Comment: There is also the `/C` switch, which gives the possibility to launch a command, but I don't know the exact command to copy the content of a file into another one. Once you know this, you can use it with the `/C` switch (together with the `@file` variable).

Answer (score 0):

This can be used as a command or in a .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:\src\t' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { if ($_.LastWriteTime -ge '2021-03-12') { $_.FullName }} |" ^
        "Out-File $(Join-Path $Env:TEMP 'newfiles.txt') -enc ascii"
```

If you are only at a cmd prompt and are desperate to shorten things, this line is equivalent. But, it is bad practice to use aliases in script files like .bat or .ps1.

```
powershell -nol -nop "gci -rec C:\src\t | %{if ($_.LastWriteTime -ge '2021-03-12') {$_.FullName }} | Out-File $(Join-Path $Env:TEMP 'newfiles.txt') -enc ascii"
```